# Reconstruction a complex-valued function from its real part on the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

This is my question. Let $a(z)$ be a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}^{+}$, and the value of $|a|$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is known. Now how can one reconstruct $a$ out of the boundary condition? My plan is to consider the function $loga(z)$ since it is well defined. Then it is also easy to show that $Re\{loga(s)\}=log|a(s)|$ for $s\in\mathbb{R}$. My question is: How can one reconstruct $loga(z)$ out of the real part of its value on the real line? Is there any formulas on this? I have tried to use certain kind of integral but failed, would Cauchy integral be of help to this? Thank you for helping!

Comment: I think you need some more conditions. For example, if $a(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$, then $|a(z)|=1$ for all real $z$, and yet $a$ is non-constant and holomorphic on the upper half-plane...

Comment: You can reconstruct outer functions in this way, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space#Factorization_into_inner_and_outer_functions_.28Beurling.29)

Comment: @40 votes: I have found the answer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_integral_formula)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Schwarz integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_integral_formula) on the upper halfplane recovers a holomorphic function from the boundary values of its real part, under the decay condition $|f(z)|=O(|z|^{-a})$  for some $a>0$:
$$f(z)=\frac1{\pi i} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Re} f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\,d\zeta\tag1$$
For one thing, the decay condition makes the integral in (1) converge. For another, it rules out functions like $iz$ (and $ie^z$, etc), which have zero real part on the real axis but are not zero identically.

When recovering $a$ from the boundary values of $|a|$, one should be aware that only [outer functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space#Factorization_into_inner_and_outer_functions_.28Beurling.29) are recovered in this way (this is basically the definition of an outer function). Blaschke products and singular inner functions are not visible in the boundary values of $u$. Blaschke products are  ruled out by requiring $a\ne 0$, while singular inner component can be ruled out by requiring $|a|$ to be to be continuous on  $\mathbb R$.

Background reading: *Banach spaces of analytic functions* by Hoffman.

*(Compilation of comments)*